# Removing unwanted info from an RSS feed from facebook

Tags: php, html, xml, facebook, rss

Lets say for example we go to this page:

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=133869316660964

How can I strip out programmatically data from that.. or pull peices of data into a variable / array for example you want the 2 latest posts (part in the  tag is it possible to acccess that?

Sorry for such an open question but I havent found a solution in some time of searching.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse it with PHP’s DOM extension: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php